# How to change the value of an attribute in Flutter based on a particular condition?

Tags: flutter

I am building the World Time app by following the tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ). The app displays the time at the location the user chooses. Also the background image is displayed in accordance to the time (a daytime image if its daytime or night image if it is night). This is done by using String variable as shown below

```
String bgImage = data['isDayTime'] ? 'day.jpg' : 'night.jpg';
//data['isDayTime'] contains true if it is day and false otherwise
//In the Body:
image: AssetImage('assets/$bgImage')
//assets is the folder containing all the images
```

I also want to change the color of the text which is displayed on the image.
I used a String variable to store the colors as follows:
`String fontColor = data['isDayTime'] ? 'black' : 'white';`
But how to use this String to set the color property in the styling of a Text widget?

```
Text(data['time'],
 style: TextStyle(
 fontSize: 66.0,
 color: ????,
))
```

I tried many variations like "color: Colors.fontColor" or "color: Colors.'&fontColor'" and so on. But none of them worked.
So how can I change the color of the text based on whether it is day or night?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the type of the fontColor from String to Color and use the code below:

```
Color fontColor = data['isDayTime'] ? Colors.black : Colors.white;
Text(data['time'],
 style: TextStyle(
 fontSize: 66.0,
 color: fontColor,
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the type String to Color for the fontColor property.

```
Color fontColor = data['isDayTime'] ? Colors.black : Colors.white;
```

Now assign the `fontColor` to your Text Widget's `color` property